# KNMultiItemSelector preselectedItems Not Working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to implement KNMultiItemSelector in my code to select multiple items in an array. I've been trying to get the selector to show some of the items as checked off upon initialization but it doesn't seem to work. My code is as follows:

```
for (Option* option in optionssList) {
        NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", option.name];
        KNSelectorItem* item = [[KNSelectorItem alloc] initWithDisplayValue:name selectValue:option.id imageUrl:nil];
        [items addObject:item];
        if ([_selectedOptions containsObject:item]) {
            NSLog(@"Already selected");
            [_selectedOptions addObject:item];
        }
    }

    KNMultiItemSelector * selector = [[KNMultiItemSelector alloc] initWithItems:items
                                                               preselectedItems:_selectedOptions
                                                                          title:@"List"
                                                                placeholderText:@"Select Options"
                                                                       delegate:self];

    selector.useRecentItems = YES;
    selector.maxNumberOfRecentItems = 5;

    UINavigationController * uinav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:selector];
    uinav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; // iPhone
    uinav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;       // iPad only
    [self presentViewController:uinav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting a bug in KNMultiItemSelector: The `KNMultiItemSelector` initializer ignores `preselectedItems`. To work around the bug, set `selected` to `YES` on the items you want selected, and ensure that `preselectedItems` is non-nil. (It need not contain the preselected items.) For example:

```
KNSelectorItem *item = [[KNSelectorItem alloc] initWithDisplayValue:@"Item"];
item.selected = YES;

KNMultiItemSelector *selector = [[KNMultiItemSelector alloc] initWithItems:@[item]
    preselectedItems:@[]
    title:@"List"
    placeholderText:@"Select Options"
    delegate:self];
```

Comment: Nevermind, this seems to be the correct answer. The version of KNMultiItemSelector included in CocoaPods just doesn't have the most recent version of the code. Thanks!